# Zend framework 2: Understanding plugins & services

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using the Zend Framework 2 for some time now. Still, I don't really understand its structure and components. It's quite possible that the reason for this is my general knowledge of PHP and associated patterns.

In particular:

- What is a service?
  I know that one of the framework's central design patterns is the service locator pattern, yet I haven't really grasped what a service is. Also, what do people mean when they talk about "implementing a service layer"?
- What is a plugin?
  I think in Zend Framework 2, the correct term is "controller plugin". To my understanding it could be just a wrapper, a class that presents a nice api for use in controllers.
  Example: Instead of calling the same 10 lines of code again & again, they can be wrapped in a controller plugin that contains a method that encapsulates these 10 lines, so the same thing can be done with one method call. Is this correct?
  If it is correct: Why should I encapsulate the code in a plugin, can't I just add it to the controller without plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ServiceLocator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator)

> The basic idea behind a service locator is to have an object that knows how to get hold of all of the services that an application might need. […] With a Service Locator every user of a service has a dependency to the locator. The locator can hide dependencies to other implementations, but you do need to see the locator.

The ZF2 PluginManager is a kind of ServiceLocator. It knows how to create Controller Plugins and controls their lifecycle. Controllers depend on the Manager.

[Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)

> Defines an application's boundary with a layer of services that establishes a set of available operations and coordinates the application's response in each operation.

ServiceLayers are usually classes with no state of their own. They only orchestrate other classes. Boundaries encapsulate certain Use Cases within your application. For details, refer to http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html.

[Plugin](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/plugin.html)

> Links classes during configuration rather than compilation. […] Configuration shouldn't be scattered throughout your application, nor should it require a rebuild or redeployment. Plugin solves both problems by providing centralized, runtime configuration.

The ZF Controller Plugins allow you to separate individual concerns, like [getting the Identity of a User, accessing Params from the Request, setting a Flash Message](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) into discrete units. Having these helps with [Separation of Concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns) and prevents [God Controllers](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/the-blob). In a nutshell: if you have code that you need to share between controllers, put it in a plugin.

Comment: Thanks – also loved the SourceMaking link, very informative!